# How to Get the GidNumber of a User in LDAP PHP

Tags: php, ldap

Stuck with this Code. I need to get the GidNumber of a particular user using PHP. Please help me in this. I have switched to get GIdNumber instead of getting MemberOf function since it is not working. Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
session_start();

$ldaphost ="ldap://(hostaddress)";
$ldapport = 389;

$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

        $person="comp1";
        $dn = "ou=Users,dc=compldap,dc=com";
        $filter="(|(sn=$person*)(givenName=$person*))";
        $justthese = array("gidNumber");

        $sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

        $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

         echo "ENTRY RESULTS: ";
        print_r($info[0]['gidNumber']);
        echo "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: No Compilation or Syntax errors in this code! It returns 0 values.

Comment: Still it shows the same result. Thanks Anyways! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter seems odd to me, try :

```
$filter="(|(sn=".$person."*)(givenName=".$person."*))";
```

Also, the `gitNumber` should be indexed like this :

```
print_r($info[0]['gidnumber'][0]);
```

Try also to check how many entries your search returned :

```
echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n";
```

EDIT :

Strangely enough I did not see that you never bind to the server before doing your search ... :

See : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-bind.php

Comment: What does that " | " in filter mean? Does it mean to take either check at least one of the conditions is true?

Comment: As you said, it shows "2 entries returned". But there is no texted output. It is Blank.

Comment: @Nithin I just added concatenation operator, I did not change your filter. But for the `|` it's an `OR` operand, which means your filter retrieve every entries which satisfy `sn=comp1* OR givenName=comp1*`. If what you need is that the entry match the 2 conditions, the filter should be `"(&(sn=".$person."*)(givenName=".$person."*))"`

Comment: @Nithin Then try to `print_r($info)` to see what is returned

Comment: It shows ( Array[count]=> 0). What does that mean? Am sorry, am new to LDAP. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Nithin It means your search returns 0 entry

Comment: And, Name followed by an asterisk , does it mean to search and retrieve all records named "comp1"?

Comment: @Estaban, I don't understand, in my output it shows as 2 Entries Returned and ( Array[count]=> 0). What does that mean?

Comment: @Nithin No, it's a wildcard. It will returned `sn=comp1`, `sn=comp12`, `sn=comp1whatever`, etc.

Comment: @Nithin I don't understand what you mean by your ouput shows 2 entries, but if the result of `ldap_get_entries` returns an array containing only `[ "count" => 0 ]`, then it means your search return 0 entry which matches the filter. See : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-get-entries.php

Comment: The output for the statement "echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n" gives value 2 , but the output for this statement "print_r($info)" gives "Array[count]=> 0".

Comment: @Nithin can you make a `var_dump($info);` ?

Comment: @Nithin I just edited my answer. I did not see that before but you have to bind to the server if you want to request it ;)

Comment: Got the required result. Thanks @Esteban for your help. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Nithin If the answer helped, marked it as correct ;)